# Limit calculation

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}((\frac94)^n+(1+\frac1n)^{n^2})^{\frac1n}$

Here's what I did:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}((\frac94)^n+(1+\frac1n)^{n^2})^{\frac1n}\\
=(\lim(\frac94)^n+\lim((1+\frac1n)^{n})^n)^{\frac1n}\\
=(\lim(\frac94)^n+\lim e^n)^{\frac1n}\\$

Any hints on how to continue?

PS: no logs/integration/derivation because we haven't covered it.

Comment: You can't push the limit inside.

Comment: I think the first step might actually be to recombine:  $$1+\frac 1n=\frac {1+n}n$$ then the next step is $$\left(\frac 94\right)^n+\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n^2}=\frac {(9n^n)^n+(n+1)^{n^2}}{(4n^n)^n}$$

Comment: @abiessu, souldn't that be: $$\frac {(9n^n)^n+4^n(n+1)^{n^2}}{(4n^n)^n}$$ ?

Also, I can't find how does that help...

Comment: You were right on my answer; I've deleted it while I think it over.

Comment: This question begs for logarithms and derivatives... Why restrict yourself?

Comment: Because we haven't covered it.

Comment: Well... you haven't done l'Hopital's Rule? Or logarithms?

Comment: No and no. This can be solved using limit arithmetic and algebra.

Comment: @ChrisK: in what way does it beg for logarithms and derivatives? I don't see how they would help simplify anything.

Comment: @GinKin: you do know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$, right?

Comment: @robjohn, after thinking about it more, it is perhaps best not to use logarithms and derivatives. However the problem of $\text{lim}\;  f(n)^{1/n}$ immediately reduces to $\text{exp}(\text{lim}\; f'(n)/f(n))$. That was my first intuition; hence the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac94\right)^n+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n}\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac94\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n}\right)^n+1\right)^{1/n}\tag{2}\\
&=e\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac94e^{-1}\right)^n+1\right)^{1/n}\tag{3}\\[9pt]
&=e\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(0+1\right)^{1/n}\tag{4}\\[18pt]
&=e\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:

$(1)$: original expression
$(2)$: bring a factor of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ outside the parentheses
$(3)$: evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$
$(4)$: evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac94e^{-1}\right)^n=0$
$(5)$: evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}1^{1/n}=1$

Comment: Please explain what and how did you do this: $ \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n \lim_{n\to\infty} (\left(\frac94(1+\frac1n)^{-n}\right)^n+1)^{1/n}  $

Comment: @GinKin: factored $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ out of the expression and put it on the left. That means dividing everything on the inside of the parentheses by $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}$.

Comment: It's basically like Matik Ken's answer. What makes me confused is PEMDAS, would you still be able to factor out even if it wasn't the $nth$ root i.e if it was to the power of n instead ?

Comment: @GinKin: step $(2)$ is only algebra. Even if the limits were not there, step $(2)$ would be valid.

Comment: @robjohn: While going from step (2) to step (3) you have replaced a part of expression with its limit (replaced $(1 + 1/n)^{-n}$ with $1/e$). Now I can intuitively understand why this works here, but in general such replacement is not allowed. Can't we add some more steps in between and show that this can be justified by some standard rules of limits.

Comment: @robjohn: May be we can put $a_{n} = (9/4)^{n}(1 + 1/n)^{-n^{2}}$ and $b_{n} = 1/n$ and show that both $a_{n}, b_{n}$ tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ and using logs show that $(1 + a_{n})^{b_{n}}$ tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: We can apply that if the family $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous at $x_\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ , then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_\infty)$.
$$
\left(\left(\frac94x\right)^n+1\right)^{1/n}\text{ is equicontinuous at }x=e^{-1}\text{ for }(3)
$$
and
$$
(x+1)^{1/n}\text{ is equicontinuous at }x=0\text{ for }(4)
$$

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for this equicontinuity result. Now I can make replacements of this kind instead of going through the longer route I suggested in my comments. It seems I am learning things every now and then at MSE.

Answer (score 3):

We know that the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by
$$
a_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
$$
converges and its limit is $e$. Notice that
$$
\left[\left(\frac94\right)^n+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\right]^{1/n}=\left[\left(\frac94\right)^n+a_n^n\right]^{1/n}=a_n\left[1+\left(\frac{9}{4a_n}\right)^n\right]^{1/n}.
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{9}{4a_n}=\frac{9}{4e}<1,
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac94\right)^n+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\right]^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\left[1+\left(\frac{9}{4a_n}\right)^n\right]^{1/n}=e(1+0)^0=e.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit is indeed $e$.

Let $a(n) = \frac94$ and $b(n) = (1+\frac1n)^n$ for $n \ge 1$.

Since $\lim b(n) = e > 9/4 = 2.25$ ( versus $2.71728\ldots$ ) there is an $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $b(n) > 9/4$. Thus $x(n)=
\frac{a(n)}{b(n)} < 1$ for $n \ge N$.

Let $S(n) =$ the original expression, then:

$S(n) = (a(n)^n + b(n)^n)^{\frac1n} = b(n)(1+(\frac{a(n)}{b(n)})^n)^{\frac1n} = b(n)r(n)$

whereas $r(n) = (1+(\frac{a(n)}{b(n)})^n)^{\frac1n}$ .

We now estimate $r(n)$. It is easy to see that $1 < r(n) < 2^{\frac1n}$ for $n \ge N$.

This means $\lim r(n) = 1$ and so $ \lim S(n) = e$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $n$, we have that $0 < \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} = \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^n < e^n$.  Thus, we can write
$$\left(1 +  \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} < \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n + \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} < \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n + e^n < 2 e^n$$
$$\left(\left(1 +  \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n} < \left(\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n + \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n} < \left(2e^n\right)^{1/n}.$$

We can use the squeeze theorem on the last inequality to obtain the limit.

Comment: Um correct me if I'm wrong but using the squeeze theorem on this inequality will yield that the limit is 9/4 but from W|A I know that the limit is e.

Comment: You're right: for some reason, when I was writing the answer, I was convinced $\frac{9}{4} = 2.75 > e$.  I fixed that, so now it should be right.

Comment: Well it seems like you just arbitrarily choose one of the two expression and apply the squeeze theorem to it. What would have happened if the expressions were more complex so you wouldn't know which one was bigger ? Also, how do you know that what you did last time was wrong without checking with W|A ? Sorry if I  don't understand enough but it seems like guesswork.

Comment: Well, first off, I decided I would try the squeeze theorem, because if $a(n) < b(n) < c(n)$, the $(a(n))^{\frac{1}{n}} < (b(n))^{\frac{1}{n}} < (c(n))^{\frac{1}{n}}$, so I can just ignore the $\frac{1}{n}$ exponent for a while, then add it back in at the end.  From there, I knew that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$, so $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^n} < e^n$.  Now, in the expression $\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n + e^n$, $e^n$ will dominate for large $n$ (since $e \approx 2.71 > 2.25 = \frac{9}{4}$), so I decided to eliminate the less important $\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n$ term.